# Keep path of the image if input is empty

Tags: php, sql

I have a form with some inputs with that form I want to make some edit in database. I want if exist a picture in databse to keep it not to replace with blank space.
Here is my code

```
<?php

include "../../../config/config.php";
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['car'])) {
    $car = $_GET['car'];
} else {
    die("Not found");
}


if (isset($_POST['submit-edit'])) {



    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['title-edit']);
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['description-edit']);
    $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['category-edit']);



    /* ----------------------- MAIN IMAGE  -------------------------- */
    $target_dir = "../../../img/found/thumbs-category/";
    $target_file2 = "" . basename($_FILES["img-edit"]["name"]);
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img-edit"]["name"]);

    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["img-edit"]["size"] > 100000) {
        $_SESSION['image-size'] = 1;

        header("Location: /dashboard/views/edit.php?car=$car");
        exit();
    }
//    
    //Allow certain file formats
    if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != NULL) {
        $_SESSION['image-format'] = 1;

        header("Location: /dashboard/views/edit.php?car=$car");
        exit();
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {

    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img-edit"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {


        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            exit();
        }


        $query = "UPDATE cars
            SET title='" . $title . "', text='" . $description . "', image='" . $target_file2 . "', fk_cars_first='" . $category . "' WHERE car=" . $car;


        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
//                var_dump($query);
//                exit();
        if ($result) {


            header("Location: /dashboard/views/edit.php?car=$car");
        } else {
//          
            echo "error";
            exit();
            header("Location: /dashboard/views/edit.php?car=$car");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

More exactly in my database I have

```
title | description | image  |  fk_category
test    more text     car.jpg   tuning
```

When I want to edit the the database I use the form and if the input with type="file" is empty I want to keep the actual path not to erase.. Right the code do something like this..I set the submit button and the database look like

```
title      | description | image  |  fk_category
testedited |   ed!t      |        |  tuning_tex_edited
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modifiy your query to update image only when needed :

```
$query = "UPDATE cars
          SET 
            title='" . $title . "', 
            text='" . $description . "', 
            fk_cars_first='" . $category . "' ";

if(!empty($target_file2)){
    $query .= ", image='" . $target_file2 . "'";
}

$query .= " WHERE car=" . $car;
```

Comment: Not working and my code is stoped at echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";

Comment: Could you post the output of this : var_dump($query);

Comment: string(103) "UPDATE cars SET title='', text='', image='', fk_cars_first='3' WHERE cars=68"

Comment: There should not be image = '', if you did what I posted.

Comment: If i add an image te string is string(108) "UPDATE cars SET title='', text='', image='7.png', fk_cars_first='3' WHERE cars=68"

Comment: Now with what you posted the query is "UPDATE cars SET title='', text='', fk_cars_first='3' WHERE cars=68". Now makes empty all the inputs..without image.

Comment: This is the same query than yours, I just added an if statement so image is updated when there is data. There is no reason that the inputs are empty.

Comment: And the error still appear "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file"

Comment: Yes, but it is caused by the upload failing, not by the query that is made after.

Comment: But how can I skip this error..upload is failing 'cause the input is empty..if is not empty the error doesen't appear.

Comment: I think I have answered your first question. What you're now asking in not relevant to the current question, maybe you could open another question.

Comment: The error still working it's relevant cause that's why the code not working.

Comment: You never mentionned this error before. I gave you an answer that solved your problem. Now you're asking for something that has no relevance to your original question. I'll just give you a few pointers anyway. Does your form have enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute ? Read documentation : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.move-uploaded-file.php, you should check that the upload went ok : if($_FILES["pictures"]["img-edit"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)

Comment: Then there is another problem for which you should open an other question, and you should close this one if the answer suits you.